# WordPress plug-in for association members management

Tags: cms, wordpress, user-management

I am working on a WordPress CMS for a student association, that requires a member management. Here are our current requirements:

New members need to be able to register themselves, filling a certain number of fields and paying a fee, either via PayPal or via in person to one of the administrators

Administrators must be able to validate manually all the sign-up of the members (after checking if they are students or external members) and to manually mark new members as having paid a fee in case a fee was paid to them in person.

Is there a WordPress module that would be able to do this task properly and store the resulting data in an SQL table?